# Why Flutter RevenueCat for iOS getOffering null?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, revenuecat, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am using Revenuecat for in app subscription for android and ios. I successfully implemented revenuecat in app subscription for android. But I am not able to implement in iOS. I have followed all the steps to setup revenuecat subscription for ios in apple developer console and revenuecat.

When I tried `Purchases.getOfferings()` it is always returning `Offerings{current:null, all:{}}`. I am running app on iOS simulator.

Comment: https://support.revenuecat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041793174-Why-are-products-empty-

Comment: You need to run it on a real device. It won't get your real offerings on a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is empty. make sure you have add these configuration.

https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/in-app-purchase-key-configuration